# How to manipulate image with jQuery - horizontal only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to manipulate the image on mouseover , that only width changes , but the height remains same. I see the image canvas doesn't fit the actual image, so I don't see his hand anymore. How can I just stretch the width?

**http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/3/**

```
div
{    
    background-image: url( http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmloy1dlrNWhp8Y2u3lEKYEnLvJAqWVhggUIrA_QwRxjenmus-Ww);
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/10/)

You don't need to use jQuery, just use pure CSS.

Remove:

```
background-size:100% 150px;
```

...and add:

```
max-height:150px;
```

Comment: I need jquery for easeOutBounce effect.

Comment: question: why did you delete the background-size, and not the other webkits?

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu ahhh.  ya, you do need jquery for that part.  ahh, sorry. I actuallyam personally using chrome so I didn't bother to remove the rest.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: weird, when I remove the webkit, it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu updated fiddle to reflect multi browser support.

Comment: what is this meaning?    background-size:100% 150px;

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu ah, sorry, it seems my firstanswer was specific to chrome.  I've updated my fiddle one last time.  It should work properly for you now.

Comment: basically, its using the length passing ability of the css3 background-size property, they dont have a good example, but you can read about it here.  Try researching some more examples too as theirs sucks.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: oh I get it now. it's more like child element and div is like parent. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that background-size can have both width and height arguments passed.  Set the width to 100% and the height to whatever static height you'd like.  Then, when the box expands, the image will get wider and not taller.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/5/

```
div
{    
    background-image: url( http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmloy1dlrNWhp8Y2u3lEKYEnLvJAqWVhggUIrA_QwRxjenmus-Ww);
    background-size: 100% 150px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Or, if you did not actually want the height on the box to change, like you have it in your original fiddle, you can simply remove that attribute from the jQuery like so:

Edit: This fiddle contains the below javascript http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/15/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").mouseenter(function(){
      $("div").animate({width:"500px"},{duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
  });
     $("div").mouseleave(function(){
         $("div").animate({width:"150px"},{duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
  });
});
```

Comment: The height of the image is fixed.  The image repeats as the box gets taller.  If you want the image to not repeat, you can set the repeat css property or simply not expand the box's height and only expand the box's width

Comment: no. I'm using Chrome, and this fiddle is not working.I see the duplicate of man.

Comment: Yes the "copy of man" is because the background image in the div is repeating along the y-axis.  The div resizing vertically was added in the code you posted.  I've edited my answer to reflect your desire to have zero height change on the box.

Comment: which browser are you using? Your fiddle is a total chaos on Chrome. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: The second version works fine in Chrome.  I think you should check it again.  I added a fiddle with the javascript update.  When I hover over the box in Chrome, it expands, the image gets wider, and nothing gets taller or repeats.

Comment: That is not the updated fiddle.  Please try using the javascript I included in the update:  http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/15/